# Is there a way in JavaScript to convert a number of seconds into a string such as "5 h 20 min", and have it localised?

Tags: javascript, time, number-formatting

Is there a way in JavaScript to convert a number of seconds into a string such as "5 h 20 min", and have it localised with the new Intl functions that were introduced into JavaScript, so in German you would have "5 Std" instead of "5 h"? I found such snippets for relative time format, but found nothing for absolute time formatted.

Comment: Why not write some code to achieve this? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Date` constructor with a fixed date and use the seconds parameter for your time data. Then use the get-functions of the date to get the hour/minute/second values.

To get the data localized read the browser language from `navigator.language`, take the first two letters as identifier and built an object map containing the translations (example in the code). Keep in mind that you need a fallback if your translation map does not contain the browser language.

```js
let translations = [
  { lang: 'en', hours: 'h', minutes: 'min', seconds: 's' },
  { lang: 'de', hours: 'std', minutes: 'min', seconds: 'sek' }
];

let t = new Date(1970 /*year*/, 1/*month*/, 1/*day*/, 0/*hours*/, 0/*minutes*/, 623 /* seconds, the interisting part */, 0 /*milliseconds*/);
let result = t.getHours() + 'h ' + t.getMinutes() + 'min ' + t.getSeconds() + 's';
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see how `toLocaleTimeString` can be used in simple examples.

```js
let fullSeconds = 8000; //example value
let hours = parseInt(fullSeconds / 3600);
fullSeconds %= 3600;
let minutes = parseInt(fullSeconds / 60);
let seconds = fullSeconds % 60;
let dt = new Date(1970, 1, 1, hours, minutes, seconds);
console.log(dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
console.log(dt.toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }))
```

You will need to look into the documentation of `toLocaleTimeString` and experiment with its use-cases to see whether it fits your requirements. If not, then you can always implement your own date formatting functions.